# Format and structure Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following structure for a Oracle DB:

Unfortunately, I have a DB that seperate the timestamp from the date.
There is the Column jDate, that includes the date in an specific format.

And there is tEnd with the following format: 0 = 00:00:00 240000 = 24:00:00 63000 = 06:30:00

Same for "tStart", but there is never a 240000 value.

I want at first the exact duration. If "tStart" = 0 and "tEnd" = 63000, then the duration ist 0.25. Then I would like to subtract 1 (one day) from "jDate", if "tEnd" <=120000 and "dTeam" = 3.

How can I adapt this on the following approach?
I have figured out some statemants already.

Do you gave any suggestions?

```
SELECT
    DATE '1900-01-01' + FLOOR("jDate" / 1000) * INTERVAL'1' YEAR+ (MOD("jDate", 1000) -1) * INTERVAL'1' DAY AS "Date",
    CASE WHEN "tEnd" =240000 THEN '23:59:59' ELSE REPLACE(TO_CHAR("tEnd", '00,00,00'),',',':') END AS "End",
    REPLACE(TO_CHAR("tStart", '00,00,00'),',',':') AS "Start",
    "IDPers" AS "ID",
    "dTeam" as "Team" FROM "GlobalDB"."UnitsDay"

WHERE   "jDate" >118000
    AND "Dep" = 1
```

Comment: Why is the duration in your example 0.25, rather than 0.27083... - are you ignoring the minutes part of the difference? Some sample data and expected results might be helpful, along with a clearer picture of what you want special values to mean - why take 1 second off 240000 - rather than use midnight the following day? And why are you sometimes subtracting a day?

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. It should be 0.27...

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. It should be 0.27... I would be greatful if you have a solution to get midnight next day for the timestamp 240000. dTeam defines the shiftstart. dTeam = 3 have an shiftstart the day before. The timestamps have a cut at 240000. This is the issue for the subtraction of one day. For example: someone works from 220000 until 80000 next day there will be two bookings. The first one will be look like jDate x I tStart 220000 I tEnd 240000. the Second one: jDate x + 1 I tStart 0 I tEnd 80000

Comment: I changed the dummy data in my answer to show that and end-'time' of 240000 does go to midnight the next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're already using floor/mod and intervals for the date conversion, you could extend that for the time portions too; and get the start/end as actual date data types. With some made-up sample data:

```
-- dummy data
with "UnitsDay" ("Dep", "dTeam", "IDPers", "jDate", "tStart", "tEnd") as (
  select 1, 1, 1, 118273, 0, 63000 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 2, 2, 118273, 160000, 240000 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 3, 118273, 0, 63000 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 4, 118273, 120000, 123456 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 5, 118273, 220000, 240000 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 5, 118274, 0, 80000 from dual
)
-- actual query
select
    date '1899-12-31'
        + floor("jDate" / 1000) * interval '1' year
        + mod("jDate", 1000) * interval '1' day
        + floor("tStart" / 10000) * interval '1' hour
        + floor(mod("tStart", 10000) / 100) * interval '1' minute
        + mod("tStart", 100) * interval '1' second
        as "Start",
    date '1899-12-31'
        + floor("jDate" / 1000) * interval '1' year
        + mod("jDate", 1000) * interval '1' day
        + floor("tEnd" / 10000) * interval '1' hour
        + floor(mod("tEnd", 10000) / 100) * interval '1' minute
        + mod("tEnd", 100) * interval '1' second
        as "End",
    "IDPers" as "ID",
    "dTeam" as "Team"
from "UnitsDay"
where "jDate" > 118000
and "Dep" = 1;
```

```
Start               End                         ID       Team
------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
2018-09-30 00:00:00 2018-09-30 06:30:00          1          1
2018-09-30 16:00:00 2018-10-01 00:00:00          2          2
2018-09-30 00:00:00 2018-09-30 06:30:00          3          3
2018-09-30 12:00:00 2018-09-30 12:34:56          4          3
2018-09-30 22:00:00 2018-10-01 00:00:00          5          3
2018-10-01 00:00:00 2018-10-01 08:00:00          5          3
```

As the 'hours' part of the time is just treated as a number, not an actual date/time, and end time of 240000 automatically adds a day - see the second and fifth rows of the output.

You can then adjust the day by one if you need to, either after getting that data, or as part of the conversion, e.g. using a case expression to modify the 'days' calculation:

```
select
    date '1899-12-31'
        + floor("jDate" / 1000) * interval '1' year
        + (
            mod("jDate", 1000)
            - case when "tEnd" < 120000 and "dTeam" = 3 then 1 else 0 end
          ) * interval '1' day
        + floor("tStart" / 10000) * interval '1' hour
        + floor(mod("tStart", 10000) / 100) * interval '1' minute
        + mod("tStart", 100) * interval '1' second
        as "Start",
    date '1899-12-31'
        + floor("jDate" / 1000) * interval '1' year
        + (
            mod("jDate", 1000)
            - case when "tEnd" < 120000 and "dTeam" = 3 then 1 else 0 end
          ) * interval '1' day
        + floor("tEnd" / 10000) * interval '1' hour
        + floor(mod("tEnd", 10000) / 100) * interval '1' minute
        + mod("tEnd", 100) * interval '1' second
        as "End",
    "IDPers" as "ID",
    "dTeam" as "Team"
from "UnitsDay"
where "jDate" > 118000
and "Dep" = 1;

Start               End                         ID       Team
------------------- ------------------- ---------- ----------
2018-09-30 00:00:00 2018-09-30 06:30:00          1          1
2018-09-30 16:00:00 2018-10-01 00:00:00          2          2
2018-09-29 00:00:00 2018-09-29 06:30:00          3          3
2018-09-30 12:00:00 2018-09-30 12:34:56          4          3
2018-09-30 22:00:00 2018-10-01 00:00:00          5          3
2018-09-30 00:00:00 2018-09-30 08:00:00          5          3
```

... although if those last two rows are supposed to represent a single shift I don't think you actually want to do that.

Either way, once you have them as dates the duration calculation becomes simple. You can use that query as an inline view, or a CTE:

```
with cte ("Start", "End", "ID", "Team") as (
    select
        date '1899-12-31'
            + floor("jDate" / 1000) * interval '1' year
            + mod("jDate", 1000) * interval '1' day
            + floor("tStart" / 10000) * interval '1' hour
            + floor(mod("tStart", 10000) / 100) * interval '1' minute
            + mod("tStart", 100) * interval '1' second,
        date '1899-12-31'
            + floor("jDate" / 1000) * interval '1' year
            + mod("jDate", 1000) * interval '1' day
            + floor("tEnd" / 10000) * interval '1' hour
            + floor(mod("tEnd", 10000) / 100) * interval '1' minute
            + mod("tEnd", 100) * interval '1' second,
        "IDPers",
        "dTeam"
    from "UnitsDay"
    where "jDate" > 118000
    and "Dep" = 1
)
select cte.*, "End" - "Start" as "Duration"
from cte;

Start               End                         ID       Team   Duration
------------------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2018-09-30 00:00:00 2018-09-30 06:30:00          1          1 .270833333
2018-09-30 16:00:00 2018-10-01 00:00:00          2          2 .333333333
2018-09-30 00:00:00 2018-09-30 06:30:00          3          3 .270833333
2018-09-30 12:00:00 2018-09-30 12:34:56          4          3 .0242592593
2018-09-30 22:00:00 2018-10-01 00:00:00          5          3 .0833333333
2018-10-01 00:00:00 2018-10-01 08:00:00          5          3 .333333333
```

Comment: That's really a different issue, and a next step on from this point (the CTE will come in handy I suspect). Search for 'gaps and islands' - it even has its own tag.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Poole! I will reseach 'gaps and island'. Why is the result for your "select 1, 3, 5, 118273, 220000, 240000 from dual" in all of your tables the date "20-10-01"? 118273 is "2018-09-30" I think. Does the code (first and last one) format/ structure the hour floor with day + 1?

Comment: The start date is calculated as 2018-09-30, but the end date ends up as 2018-10-01 because the 240000 adds 24 hours to that, making it midnight next day - which is what you wanted?

Comment: That sounds perfect! This is the way how it should work! Many thanks!

Comment: Is there any performance benefit at using cte? Do you have some other points to reduce the loading? It is just for research and learning. I dont need a new code. Your code works perfectly!